Pylint warnings with attrs
I keep getting warnings from pylint while trying to iterate over an attribute in a class that uses the attrs package.
from typing import List
from attrs import define, Factory

@define
class MyClass:
  my_list: List[str] = Factory(list)

  def my_method(self):
    for i in self.my_list:
      continue

I expect no problems but get Non-iterable value is using in an iterating context from pylint.
Found some older threads mentioning poor compatibility of pylint with attrs but I though it would be better now.
Is there anything I can do different instead of ignore this warnings?

Factory objects should be passed to the default argument of field, not directly as fields. The following works for me and satisfies both pylint 3.2.6  and mypy 1.10.1 on Python 3.10.14
from typing import List
from attrs import define, field, Factory


@define
class MyClass:
    my_list: List[str] = field(default=Factory(dict))

    def my_method(self):
        for i in self.my_list:
            continue

